# Percentage Calculation optimization

Tags: java, performance

I have two BigDecimal values, and I have to calculate and store the % profit for a few million products, i.e.:

```
Integer profit = ((sold - cost)/sold) * 100
```

Only positive values are stored.

I currently have this:

```
Integer profit = null;
if (sold == null || cost == null || cost.compareTo(sold)>0) {
        profit = null;
} else {
    final BigDecimal difference_x100 = sold.subtract(cost).movePointRight(2);
    final BigDecimal percentage = priceDifference_x100.divideToIntegralValue(sold);
    final int percentageInt = percentage.intValue();
    profit = percentageInt > 0 ? percentageInt : null;
}
```

Which changes can I make to improve the performance of this method? Would bitwise operation make an improvement?

Comment: You have to use necessary `BigDecimal` ?  Because it seems me from your scenario you can use`Float` or `Double` values.

Comment: I would have liked to use int, i.e: work with cents rather than dollar, but I am given two BigDecimals as input

Comment: Either use the **database** to do the percentage calculation, or do it lazy at the view size. DB seems likely in this case. (By the way `OptionalInt` just might be an idea here instead of a nullable Integer.)

Comment: @dariosicily Float or Double would be a bad choice here because of rounding issues. Try adding two Doubles 0.1 and 0.2 and you'll see what i mean.

Comment: @JoopEggen it is  a NoSQL db ... otherwise I would have used a calculated column.

Comment: The high-level answer is simple: If you want to improve the performance, don't use `BigDecimal`. You should also **not** use `float` or `double` because of the rounding issues. But it should not be a problem to do the calculation using `long`, where you store the price in *cents*. The crucial question then is: Do the prices that you receive as input always have at most 2 decimal places, or can you also have a price of "123 dollars and 456.789 cents"? In any case, you should also get rid of the special meaning of `null` in your function. Just don't call it when you don't have sensible inputs...

Comment: @Cwrwhaf thanks, I hadn't considered rounding issues.

Comment: @Cwrwhaf In principle, double gives you enough precision to derive an integer percentage.

Answer (score 0):

As a slight aside, you can tidy up your code a little by not setting profit to null again:

```
if (!(sold == null || cost == null || cost.compareTo(sold)>0)) {
    final BigDecimal difference_x100 = sold.subtract(cost).movePointRight(2);
    final BigDecimal percentage = priceDifference_x100.divideToIntegralValue(sold);
    final int percentageInt = percentage.intValue();
    profit = percentageInt > 0 ? percentageInt : null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Would bitwise operation make an improvement?

In my experience it is not easy to beat optimizing compilers (both at compile time an JIT) on that level. It's even not easy to measure (has to be production context exactly).

But, do you need BigDecimal for sure, e.g. because of very large numbers, or special rounding issues?
If not, try using long instead, calculating with cents. int and long are much faster in processing than float and double, which are again much faster than BigDecimal.

Even if you receive BDs, converting them to long for the calculation is much fuster. I did a small test piece with 10.000 BigDecimal values, and the outcome was 565 ms vs. 149 ms (incl. the conversion from and to bd).

```
public static void longmethod(BigDecimal psold, BigDecimal pcost) {
    long sold = psold.scaleByPowerOfTen(2).longValue();
    long cost = pcost.scaleByPowerOfTen(2).longValue();
    final long difference_x100 = (sold - cost) * 100;
    final long percentage = sold == 0?0:difference_x100/sold;
    final BigDecimal bdpercentage = new BigDecimal(percentage);
}
```

Comment: psold.longValue will discard any cents, i.e. any value less than $1, will be 0

Comment: @halfpad I suggested to make the calculation in cents, so multiplying by 100.